# Show that $\mathcal{T}=\{\emptyset, \mathbb{R}^2, \underset{\epsilon>0}{\bigcup}B_\epsilon(\vec{0})\}$ is a topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology

> Show that $\mathcal{T}=\{\emptyset, \mathbb{R}^2, \underset{\epsilon>0}{\bigcup}B_\epsilon(\vec{0})\}$ is a topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$

$\underset{\epsilon>0}{\bigcup}B_\epsilon(\vec{0})$ is all open discs centered at the origin.

So to show this is a topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ I need to show $\emptyset,\mathbb{R}^2\in \mathcal{T}$, that there is closure under arbitrary unions and there is closure under finite intersection.

1. $\emptyset,\mathbb{R}^2$ are given to be in $\mathcal{T}$
2. Let $\underset{\alpha \in S}{\bigcup}U_\alpha$ be a union of sets in $\mathcal{T}$

If $\mathbb{R}^2$ is in this set we know that $\underset{\alpha \in S}{\bigcup}U_\alpha\in\mathcal{T}$, so assume it is a subset of open discs, $\underset{\epsilon \in S}{\bigcup}B_\epsilon(\vec{0})$.

Since $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, either $S$ has a supremum or $S$ is unbounded.

If $S$ has a supremum, so that $N>s$ for all $s\in S$.

then if $x\in\underset{\epsilon \in S}{\bigcup}B_\epsilon(\vec{0})$

there is some $\epsilon>0$ such that $x\in B_\epsilon(\vec{0})$

but since $N$ is the $\sup$ of $S$, $\epsilon\leq N$

thus $x\in B_N(\vec{0})$ as $\vert\vert x-0\vert\vert<\epsilon\leq N$

If $S$ is not bounded from above, then for any $\vec{x}\in \mathbb{R}^2$

$\vert\vert \vec{x}-\vec{0}\vert\vert=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}$

By Archimedian property there exists an $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n>\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}$

and since $S$ contains all $\epsilon>0$ then $n\in S$

thus $\vec{x}\in B_n(\vec{0})$

Also if $\vec{x}\in B_\epsilon(\vec{0})$ for some $\epsilon>0$ then $x\in \mathbb{R}^2$

thus $\mathbb{R}^2=\underset{\epsilon \in S}{\bigcup}B_\epsilon(\vec{0})\in \mathcal{T}$

3. Suppose $x\in \underset{i=1}{\overset{k}\bigcap}U_i$

If one of $U_i$ is $\emptyset$ we are done since $\emptyset\in \mathcal{T}$

Thus assume $x\in \underset{i=1}{\overset{k}\bigcap}U_i=x\in \underset{i=1}{\overset{k}\bigcap}B_{\epsilon_i}(\vec{0})$ where $\epsilon_i>0$

Since $i\in \{1,...,k\}$ is a finite set, there exists an infimum.

Thus there exists a $\epsilon_j$ such that $\epsilon_j\leq \epsilon$ for all $i\in \{1,...,k\}$

Want to show that $\underset{i=1}{\overset{k}\bigcap}B_{\epsilon_i}(\vec{0})= B_{\epsilon_j}(\vec{0})$

Thus if $x\in B_{\epsilon_j}(\vec{0})$ then $\vert\vert x-\vec{0}\vert\vert<\epsilon_j\leq\epsilon_i$ for all $i$, thus $x\in B_{\epsilon_i}(\vec{0})$ for all $i$, so $x\in \underset{i=1}{\overset{k}\bigcap}B_{\epsilon_i}(\vec{0})$

suppose $x\in \underset{i=1}{\overset{k}\bigcap}B_{\epsilon_i}(\vec{0})$

then $x\in B_{\epsilon_i}(\vec{0})$ for all $i\in \{1,...,k\}$

then $\vert\vert x-\vec{0}\vert\vert <e_i$ for all $i\in \{1,...,k\}$

thus $\vert\vert x-\vec{0}\vert\vert$ is a lower bound for the set of $e_i$

thus by definition of infimum, $\vert\vert x-\vec{0}\vert\vert\leq e_j$

> I believe I'm close to the idea. I'm pretty sure in $2.$ I can say every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is either bounded or unbounded so I believe that proof works. My main problem is the last line of $3.$ I get that $\vert\vert x-\vec{0}\vert\vert\leq e_j$ by definition of infimum but seems to leave open the possibly that $x$ is in the boundary of $B_{\epsilon_j}(\vec{0})$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mistake in notation: the topology is $$\{0, \mathbb{R}^2\} \cup \{B_\epsilon(0)\}_{\epsilon > 0}.$$

On the closed under arbitrary unions part. If $S$ is bounded, the first part is correct but you are missing the second. You want to show $\cup_{\epsilon \in S} B_\epsilon(0) = B_N(0)$. You have shown $\cup_{\epsilon \in S} B_\epsilon(0) \subset B_N(0)$ but not the opposite inclusion.

If $S$ is unbounded, the idea is correct but the execution is not. You want to show $\cup_{\epsilon \in S} B_\epsilon(0) = \mathbb{R}^2$. The inclusion $\cup_{\epsilon \in S} B_\epsilon(0) \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is as you have done. But the issue with the opposite inclusion is $S$ being unbounded does not imply $S$ contains all $\epsilon > 0$. What it does imply is that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists $s \in S$ such that $s > n$. For instance, if $S = \{0.5, 1.5, 2.5, \cdots\}$ then $S$ is unbounded but does not contain any natural numbers. (In fact you do not even require the Archimedean property; it's enough that for all $\delta > 0$ there exists $s \in S$ such that $s > n$. Then consider a 'smart' value of $\delta$.)

On the closed under finite intersection part. Note a finite set always has a minimum, which is equal to the infimum. Saying it has a minimum is better in this case because it emphasises membership, i.e. that $\epsilon_j \in \{\epsilon_1, \cdots, \epsilon_k\}$. I'll leave you to think about how, but this resolves your concerns in the last proof.

As a remark, your concerns in the last proof 'validate' in a sense why we only permit closure under finite intersections; indeed, if we permitted countable intersections then it's possible $\cap_{\epsilon \in S} B_\epsilon(0)$ could be a *closed* ball, not an open ball.

Comment: So to show that $\cup_{\epsilon\in S}B_\epsilon(0)\subseteq B_N(0)$. I need to use the property of supremum that if $d(x,0)<N$ then there exists an $r>0$ such that $d(x,0)<r\leq N$ with $r\in S$?

Comment: Close; I think you mean the opposite inclusion. Anyway, you need to replace $r \leq N$ with $r < N$. Otherwise you permit $r = N$ but of course the supremum doesn’t have to be an element of the set itself. In any case, the idea is right; if such an $r$ does not exist then $d(x,0)$ is a strictly smaller upper bound.

Comment: Don't I need to permit $r=N$? Since it could be the case that the supremum is in the set?

Comment: Of course - sorry, my bad. You're absolutely right, $S = \{N\}$ is entirely possible. What you've done is fine; if $N \in S$ then $r = N$, and if $N \notin S$ then $d(x, 0) < r < N$.